What's the max output current for Z80 PIO output pins - (Z84C2010VE6)?
I'm working with a Zeal 8bit board and I want to connect the pins from Z80 PIO Port A to external components, let says LEDs. With a 2.2k resistor and a 5V power supply the calculated current is 1.5 mA.
The board uses a Z84C2010VE6, and I have not found any information about max. output current for Port A. As for Port B, datasheet mentions 1.5 mA max, requiring darlington transistor for interfacing. Port B is already used by the system (UART, I2C).

Does anyone have any idea what the current limit might be?
I already asked to the board developer, but him is also in the dark.

The DC characteristics table shows an 'output high' voltage of 2.4V measured at a current of 1.6mA, so it can apparently supply at least the same order of current.  Is there any reason to not include a buffering transistor, just in case?

@dave. No problem with that. Being a "modern" board, I thought that it will be 20 mA at 5 V, like an Arduino.

@CandidMoe That is a modern board but uses an old chip, providing the chip IO directly. And no, as there is no single "Arduino", you can't state an Arduino can provide 20mA at 5V even based on one board. Also highly alarming that the board designer also did not read the data sheet and cannot provide a value or tell how to find it - makes me think what might be wrong and used incorrectly on the board.

The data sheet for Z84C20 series (i.e. the CMOS version you have) says the following:
Vol = 0.4V max when sinking in 2.0 mA
Voh = 2.4V min when sourcing out 1.6 mA
Voh = VCC-0.8V min when sourcing out 0.25 mA
That does not mean it can't provide slightly more but it does not say a safe amount.
The data sheet says the Z8420 series NMOS version has a special Darlington drivers on Port B that can drive out 1.5 mA. But you don't have this chip.
